# jQuery fetch data and show on HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've made a comment section for a project that lists each picture uploaded by a user. jQuery is used to toggle the view comments button and show the related comments to that picture. An Ajax request fetches the data from database.

Now the problem is that only the first picture seems to show the comments and not the rest of the below.

#### jQuery

```
    var array1, array2, iden, value, repeat;

    function fetching(iden) {
        value = iden.data("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'fetchertwo' %}",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'search': value
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                array1 = data.content;
                array2 = data.author;
                $.each(array1, function(i, item) {
                    iden.find($(".paratwo")[i]).html( array2[i]+'\n')
                    console.log(array1[i], array2[i]);
                });
            }
        });
     }

     $('.headingone').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         iden = $(event.target).next()
         $(this).next().toggle("slide");
         fetching(iden)
     });

     $('.formtwo').on("submit", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log(iden)
         var formData = $(this).serialize();
         $.post("/usercreation/picomment/" + value, formData,
                function(response) {
                    fetching(iden)
                });
         this.reset();
     });
```

#### HTML

```
<a style="text-decoration:blink;" href="" class="headingone" data-id={{item.pk}} >View Comments</a>

<div class="menu" data-id={{item.pk}} style="display:none">
    {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
        <p class="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"></p>
    {% endfor %}
    <form class="formtwo" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input data-id={{item.pk}} autocomplete="off"  type="text" name="commentadd" class="form-control commentadd" placeholder="Add Comment">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insertBefore` to insert items and `.html()` overwrite the previous content.

Add a div for your comments:

```
<div id="comments">
  {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
    <p class="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"></p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>


success: function(data) {
  array1 = data.content;
  array2 = data.author;

  const comments = [];
  $.each(array1, function(i, item) {
       comments.push('<p class="paratwo">' + array1[i] + '<br> by:' + array2[i] + '</p>');
  });
  $('#comments').html(comments.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, one more question. Now suppose i have opened the comment section and below that is a form to add a new comment. Now say my current comments are "hey" and "sup".  Then after submitting a new one (lets say "yoo"), i see "hey","sup","hey","sup","yoo"